# Getting Error while generating signed apk for Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, signed-apk

Getting bellow Error while generating signed APK for android wear.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Although when I'm debugging, its running flawlessly in device or emulator. But the above issue occurs every time I try to generate the signed APK for Android-Wear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved the issue I edited build.gradle file of both mobile and wear module. add "     multiDexEnabled true " inside of defaultConfig{} of "build.gradle" file of both mobile and wear module. samples are bellow.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       ....
             multiDexEnabled true
        ...  
    }
}
```